# Does setting an object to nothing also set it's child objects to nothing?

Tags: oop, asp-classic

Say I have an object, Email, one of whose properties is an object called EmailSkinner.

The EmailSkinner is instantiated in the class_initialize subroutine like this.

```vb
private sub class_initialize()
    set EmailSkinner = new MyEmailSkinner
end sub
```

Must I explicitly set the EmailSkinner object to nothing in the class_terminate subroutine of Email?

```vb
private sub class_terminate()
    set EmailSkinner = nothing
end sub
```

Or does this happen automatically when I set the Email object itself to nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Your assumption is correct any object's you instantiate inside the scope of the parent class will be released when the parent class is released from memory.

However as with all object instantiation in VBScript (and by extension Classic ASP) there is nothing wrong with explicitly releasing objects using the `Class_Terminate` event.

Remember though that "scope" is important here.

If your `EmailSkinner` object reference is declared outside of the parent class (regardless of whether it is instantiated inside the class) the reference will remain and will require `Class_Terminate()` to force the object reference to be released.

### Examples

Object Reference is declared inside Class scope.

```vb
Class ParentObject
  Private _ChildObject

  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set _Object = new ChildObject()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Object Reference is declared outside Class scope (*wouldn't recommend this approach*).

```vb
Dim GlobalObject

Class ParentObject
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set GlobalObject = new ChildObject()
  End Sub

  'GlobalObject reference will remain so we need to
  'force it to be released.
  Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set GlobalObject = Nothing
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Class objects are auto destroyed, but if you create new objects outside, you will need to release them from memory .

Is always recommended that we clean memory in all scenarios .

I made a small piece of code for you to test ( I hope this would be similar to what you are trying to explain, since you didn't show us your code ) .

This code help us to check if something remains in memory after some steps of execution and declaration ( just take out the apostrophes at bottom to test the code  ) :

```js
 Class EmailSkinner
 public color
 public size
  Private Sub Class_Initialize
  color = "blue"
  size = 300
  End Sub
 End Class

 Class Email
 public details
 public name
 Private Sub Class_Initialize
  Set details = New EmailSkinner  '//Module Scope
  End Sub
 Private Sub Class_Terminate
  Set details = Nothing
  End Sub
 End Class

 Set email1 = New Email                 '//Global Scope
 With email1
  .details.color = "black"
  .details.size = 400
 End With

 ''//Take out the apostrophe to test one of the next lines
 'Response.Write email1.details.color '//ASP only
 'wscript.echo email1.details.color '//Wscript only
 
 Set email1 = Nothing
```

Comment: How do you suppose stack snippets work in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure that code really demonstrates anything especially when you start off with `age` and end with `size`. The reason I kept my examples simple.

Comment: That's only a sample for testing, like I said, you must run the code in a proper environment like everyone else. Thanks for your interest m8 .

Comment: I know what it is, but what does it show? Where have you demonstrated different scope instantiation or even setting the references to `Nothing` to show how that affects the outcome?

Comment: My dear friend , I think this is not a chat, we're not here to compete, the better it will be to let the author decide if the answers help him. If the author thinks that your answer is the best, nobody gets angry with this. If you read my comment and observe the code, understand, what part is that the memory is affected or not, cheers.

Comment: Hey you're entitled to write an answer I'm just confused as to why you felt it necessary. Was there something wrong with my explanation? If studying your answer led me to the conclusion I had missed something I wouldn't be bothered but I fail to see what extra benefit you have brought to the table. So far you have provided sample code which doesn't really explain scope at all and paraphrased my answer, do you see my issue?

Comment: Why go back to the stack snippet it's pointless server-side code can be run in stack snippets. You have also undone the formatting changes making it harder to read your code attempt. I give up your obviously beyond help.

Comment: Oh I see it's like that well [SO maintains revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27641709/3) - First you credit someone then you remove it when you don't like what they say, real mature. Next you'll down-vote my answer no doubt.